# simple_form show selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to show a select box with users, using simple_form.

currently my code looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :user, collection: get_members, label_method: :fullname %>
```

this is working, but the problem is that the select box doesn't show the selected option.

Does anybody know how to show a selected option with simple_form?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set selected to the value of the user_id, but simple_form should be smart enough to figure this out by itself, so probably something wrong somewhere else (controller?):

```
   <%= f.input :user, collection: get_members, label_method: :fullname, selected: member.id %>
```

Sorry, you probably need f.association:

```
f.association :user, collection: get_members
```

Comment: thanks bo-oz, using f.association solved the problem

Comment: YW southern neighbour!